# how to find info regarding handlers using ansible-doc command in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Is it possible to find info or example about handlers using ansible-doc command in ansible? ansible-doc is very useful finding info about various modules . Is it possible to find info or and example about handlers using ansible-doc?